# Isempty() in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck in Selenium since FindElements.IsEmpty() is not available in selenium c#.
Basically after login i need to check if cancel button exists on DOM.
If yes then we have to initiate click action.
I have created a Page Object Model but i am not getting how to take action on cancel  button.
Below is my code

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
namespace Basic_Test
{
    class Login
    {
        public Login()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(PropertyCollection.driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "UserNameInputText")]
        public IWebElement txtEnterUser { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Brand")]
        public IWebElement ddlSelectBrand { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "CmdLogin")]
        public IWebElement Click { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Cancel")]
        public IWebElement Cancel { get; set; }
        public static IWebElement FindElementSafe(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            try
            {
                return driver.FindElement(by);
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public static Boolean Exists(this IWebElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
            { return false; }
            return true;
        }

        
        public MessageBoardPageObject Dologin(string username)
        {

            txtEnterUser.SendKeys(username);
            Click.Submit();
            if (Exists(Cancel))
            {
                Cancel.Click();
            }
            
            return new MessageBoardPageObject();
        }
            

        

            
           
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can use isEnabled()

Answer (score 3):

```
try
{
    if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath")) != null)
    {
        IWebElement buttonclick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath"));
        buttonclick.Click();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //in case there is an exception
}
```

Comment: did this work for you? If so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You use Size function,

```
 if(driver.findElements(By.Locator).size() > 0)
//Exists
else
//Not exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom method like

```
private bool IsControlPresent(By Control)
{
    try
    {

         WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
         WebDriver.FindElement(Control);         
         WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
         return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IsEmpty is not there in C# selenium. Either u can check for not null or Displayed == true, Displayed is a property in C# it will return true or false.

```
    IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    var element = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cancel-button"));
    if(element!=null && element.Displayed)
    {
          element.Click();
    }
    else
    {
           Assert.Fail("Element not Found"); 
/*for Assert Use MSTest Framework Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting*/
    }
```